# Whilie forming google map search URL, Is it possible to pass zoom parameter? if yes, how? if not, any alternative?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to create simple google map hyperlink/URL with specific latitude,longitude,zoom settings. I want marker to be displayed on map.

Google map documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) says for search action only query and query_place_id parameters can be set, no mention of how to set zoom.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add z=your_level

```
 https://maps.google.com/?q=38.6531004,-90.243462&ll=38.6531004,-90.243462&z=3
```

or

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796&z=3
```

Comment: Thanks. First link works for me, second one doesn't.